# Repairing a thin cut in exhaust pipe

Tags: exhaust

I am looking for a way to repair a small hole I created in my exhaust.  The hole is about 1 to 1.5 inches long and only about the width of a cutting wheel (you can guess how the hole got there).  I was considering using a jb weld type product but i fear that it won't fill the hole i created.

Any advice is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a wrap and clamp to seal the hole. Your local parts store should have such a kit.

Or the better solution would be to weld it shut, or cut out the section of pipe where the hole is, and weld in a new section of pipe to replace it.

Comment: as they say, more than one way to skin a cat.  thank you for your answers

Comment: I'd definitely recommend the welding option. Clamping the hole shut will do little to nothing to strengthen the tube, whereas a good weld will restore it to its original strength. This gets more important the further away the damage is from the closest mounting point.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for something approximately like this, only in the size you actually need: [exhaust band clamp](http://shop.advanceautoparts.com/p/walker-aluminized-band-clamp-4-butt-joint-33312/18371105-p?cm_mmc=ACQ-_-Google-_-GPLA-_-18371105&ci_src=17588969&ci_sku=18371105&ci_gpa=pla_with_promotion&ci_kw=&iv_=__iv_p_1_n_g_a_pla_with_promotion_d_6201684_f_online_s__o_18371105_z_US_j_71043851422_i_en_d_c_v___vi&gclid=CK2Y58-QscACFeRj7Aods0YA-Q)

Comment: That's how Landrover owners do it!

Comment: Say, if you're around, you might want to check this link...  It's dead.

Comment: Ah, crud. Here's another just like it: https://www.summitracing.com/parts/sum-693300